# SQLAlchemy many to many relationships confusion

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, associations

Consider the following model(from pythoncentral tutorials):

```
class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    employees = relationship(
        'Employee',
        secondary='department_employee_link'
    )


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    hired_on = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    departments = relationship(
        Department,
        secondary='department_employee_link'
    )


class DepartmentEmployeeLink(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department_employee_link'
    department_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('department.id'), primary_key=True)
    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String(256))
    department = relationship(Department, backref=backref("employee_assoc"))
    employee = relationship(Employee, backref=backref("department_assoc"))
```

I understand that this piece of code establishes a many-many relationship between employees and depts.Suppose I have to insert the department_id and employee_id into the DepartmentEmployee link table, how do I do it?? The tutorial says:

```
>>> IT = Department(name="IT")
>>> John = Employee(name="John")
>>> John_working_part_time_at_IT = DepartmentEmployeeLink(department=IT, employee=John, extra_data='part-time')
>>> s = session()
>>> s.add(John_working_part_time_at_IT)
>>> s.commit()
```

But I want to do it separately. first, I want to add details into the department table, then the employee table. Finally, I need to populate the Dept-employee link where the user enters the extra_data column alone... How do I do this?
I tried doing something like this

```
def mapper:
    que=DBSession.query(Department)
    que2=DBSession.query(Strings)


                        rel=DepartmentEmployeeLink(extra_data=str(x))//__init__ed this
                        rel.department=que
                        rel.employee=que.employees[0].id

            DBSession.add(rel)
```

This is how I want the insertion to happen since I already have data inside department and employee. Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this i.e., inserting into the link table if I have data in the other 2 tables?

I learnt there's a way to do this like "employees.append.xxx" but I dont understand.. Can someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way to define [Many to Many relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) in SQLAlchemy using association_table.

```
association_table = Table('department_employee_link', Base.metadata,
    Column('departmant_id', Integer, ForeignKey('department.id')),
    Column('employee_id', Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'))
)


class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    employees = relationship(
        'Employee',
        secondary=association_table
    )


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    hired_on = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    departments = relationship(
        Department,
        secondary=association_table
    )


IT = Department(name="IT")
John = Employee(name="John")
IT.employees.append(John)
s = session()
s.add(IT)
s.commit()
```

Comment: IT = Department(name="IT")
John = Employee(name="John")
These two lines insert into Department and Employee table or just query? I dont think you should s.add(John) it will throw an error missing coilumn. The docs in the Pycentral link dont add these. WHy? Also, can you please tell me how do I get the list of employees in It department in a query?

Comment: And, If i already have data inserted into Departments , how do I add employees? SOmething like myvar=DBSession.query(department).filter(Department=IT) ; myvar.employees.append(John)? Thats my question.. Also how do I find the department of an employee?

Comment: it_department = s.query(Department).filter(Department.name = "IT");

it_employees = it_department.employees;

erick = Employee(name="Erick");

it_department.employees.append(erick);

s.commit();

john = s.query(Employee).filter(Employee.name = "John");

johns_departments = john.departments;

Comment: I get an empty list inside john.departments :(

Comment: gives out attributeerror: query object has no attribute "employees"

Comment: Sorry! My fault! Need to add .all() or .first() or .one() depending on how many results you are planning to get from a query.

it_department = s.query(Department).filter(Department.name = "IT").first(); it_employees = it_department.employees; erick = Employee(name="Erick"); it_department.employees.append(erick); s.commit(); john = s.query(Employee).filter(Employee.name = "John").first(); johns_departments = john.departments;

Comment: john = s.query(Employee).filter(Employee.name = "John").first();
deptid=DBSession.query(Departments).filter(Departments.department==IT).first()
deptid.employees.append(john)
//I can add any number of employees to IT dept this way but...
                
                      
                        print deptid.employees[0].name This gives me the name John(myfirst inserted name). How do I print the list of all employees in IT dept? print deptid.employees.name gives out an error

Comment: for employee in deptid.employees: print employee.name Please feel free to mark my answer as accepted! :)

Comment: You definitely deserve an upvote and an accept. But I still get this attribute error. can you please help me out?

Comment: Наve you tried: for employee in deptid.employees: print employee.name ?

Comment: That just gives out the first name. Now I have multiple employees in It dept I want all of them to be appended.deptid=DBSession.query(Departments).filter(Departments.department==IT).first() deptid.employees.append(john).. SUppose I have multiple johns. How will I append? .all() returns the error list object has no sa_instance

Comment: Lets say this is the list of employees you need to append: employees = [John, Mark, Erick]. Now you do: deptid.employees += employees.

Comment: No I should get the list of employees via query.. I dont have a list.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Query employees. The result is a list of objects. Then just add this list to the list of department employees. And commit the changes.

Comment: unfortunately, the list object is not iterable :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72750/discussion-between-tania-and-tim-osadchiy).